prlimit: failed to set the NOFILE resource limit: Operation not permitted
I have a elasticsearch, I want to set process NOFILE to unlimited.
prlimit --nofile=430000:430000 --pid 3359088 worked, I can see it changed in /proc/3359088/limits, but prlimit --nofile=unlimited:unlimited --pid 3359088 failed:
root@elasticsearch:/proc/3359088# sudo prlimit --nofile=unlimited --pid 3359088
prlimit: failed to set the NOFILE resource limit: Operation not permitted

Here is it's systemd service file:
[Unit]
Description=Elasticsearch
Documentation=https://www.elastic.co
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=notify
RuntimeDirectory=elasticsearch
PrivateTmp=true
Environment=ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch
Environment=ES_PATH_CONF=/etc/elasticsearch
Environment=PID_DIR=/var/run/elasticsearch
Environment=ES_SD_NOTIFY=true
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/elasticsearch

WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/elasticsearch

User=elasticsearch
Group=elasticsearch

ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet

# StandardOutput is configured to redirect to journalctl since
# some error messages may be logged in standard output before
# elasticsearch logging system is initialized. Elasticsearch
# stores its logs in /var/log/elasticsearch and does not use
# journalctl by default. If you also want to enable journalctl
# logging, you can simply remove the "quiet" option from ExecStart.
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit

# Specifies the maximum file descriptor number that can be opened by this process
LimitNOFILE=420000

# Specifies the maximum number of processes
LimitNPROC=4096

# Specifies the maximum size of virtual memory
LimitAS=infinity

# Specifies the maximum file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity

# Disable timeout logic and wait until process is stopped
TimeoutStopSec=0

# SIGTERM signal is used to stop the Java process
KillSignal=SIGTERM

# Send the signal only to the JVM rather than its control group
KillMode=process

# Java process is never killed
SendSIGKILL=no

# When a JVM receives a SIGTERM signal it exits with code 143
SuccessExitStatus=143

# Allow a slow startup before the systemd notifier module kicks in to extend the timeout
TimeoutStartSec=75

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# Built for packages-7.17.5 (packages)


My OS is: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and kernel version is 5.4.0-122-generic
